# MSVC++: template's static_assert is not triggered inside a lambda

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

**Update 2:**

This is fixed now in VS 2019 Preview 16.1 Preview 1.

**Update:**

I have filed a bug report at [visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/257084/templates-static-assert-is-not-triggered-inside-a.html).

---

So I'm starting to get into C++'s templates and I ran into this issue when trying to prevent a template class from being compiled using `static_assert`.

Basically, the `static_assert` error is not triggered when it is inside a lambda on VS2017 using **C++ Language Standard: ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)**.

I also tried this on gcc-7 using **-std=c++17** and the error is triggered. Is this a bug on VS2017 or is there something I'm missing?

**Code sample:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class IntegralContainer
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Type must be an integral!");
};

template<typename T>
class IntegralContainer<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type >
{
private:
    T _value;

public:
    IntegralContainer(T value)
        : _value(value)
    {
    }
};

int main()
{
    IntegralContainer<int> int_container(1);
    // static_assert message is shown here.
    // > error C2338: Type must be an integral!
    // IntegralContainer<std::string> str_container;

    []() {
        // static_assert is not triggered here.
        IntegralContainer<std::string> str_container;
    }();

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/sdu6pd), it looks like it optimizes the contents of the lambda away before it even triggers the error (which would be a bug)...

Comment: But if you give the primary template a default constructor with side effects, those side effects do happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's optimising away code which can never be executed.
Definitely a bug. The lambda is undergoing some (probably semantic substitution) basic optimisation.

The resulting assembly shows no code being generated for the line
    IntegralContainer str_container

```
  []() {
00F72280  push        ebp  
00F72281  mov         ebp,esp  
00F72283  sub         esp,0D8h  
00F72289  push        ebx  
00F7228A  push        esi  
00F7228B  push        edi  
00F7228C  push        ecx  
00F7228D  lea         edi,[ebp-0D8h]  
00F72293  mov         ecx,36h  
00F72298  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00F7229D  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
00F7229F  pop         ecx  
00F722A0  mov         dword ptr [this],ecx  
    // static_assert is not triggered here.
    IntegralContainer<std::string> str_container;
  }();
00F722A3  push        edx  
00F722A4  mov         ecx,ebp  
00F722A6  push        eax  
00F722A7  lea         edx,ds:[0F722BCh]  
00F722AD  call        @_RTC_CheckStackVars@8 (0F712B2h)  
00F722B2  pop         eax  
00F722B3  pop         edx  
00F722B4  pop         edi  
00F722B5  pop         esi  
00F722B6  pop         ebx  
00F722B7  mov         esp,ebp  
00F722B9  pop         ebp  
00F722BA  ret
```

If the static assert is placed inside a public ctor though.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
class IntegralContainer
{
public:
  IntegralContainer(T const& value) {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Type must be an integral!");
  }
};

template<typename T>
class IntegralContainer<T, typename std::enable_if< std::is_integral<T>::value >::type >
{
private:
  T _value;

public:
  IntegralContainer(T value)
    : _value(value)
  {
  }
};

int main()
{
  IntegralContainer<int> int_container(1);
  // static_assert message is shown here.
  // > error C2338: Type must be an integral!
  //IntegralContainer<std::string> str_container;

  []() {
    // static_assert is not triggered here.
    IntegralContainer<std::string> str_container(std::string(""));
  }();

  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";

  return 0;
}
```

The static_assert is triggered.

Comment: AFAICT the preprocessor is blameless in this also.